Show that an operator is not compact.
Let $C[0,1]$ denote the Banach space of all continuous complex-valued functions on $[0,1]$ with norm
$$
\|f\|_{\infty} = \sup\{|f(x)| : x \in [0,1]\}.
$$
Let $g : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a non-constant continuous function. Consider the operator $T : C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ defined by $Tf = f \circ g$, that is,
$Tf(x) = f(g(x))$ for all $f \in C[0,1]$ and $x \in [0,1]$.
Show that the image of the unit ball in $C[0,1]$ under $T$ is not compact in $C[0,1]$.
Idea is to use Arzelà-Ascoli theorem
Let $\|f_n\|_{\infty}=1 \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$
Since each $f_n$ is uniformly continuous we have $\forall \epsilon>0$ there exist $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$, $|f_n(x)-f_n(y))|<\epsilon_n$
and foe same delta we have $|g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon.$
$|Tf_n(x)-Tf_n(y)|=|f_n(g(x)-f_n(g(y))|<\epsilon_n|g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon_n \epsilon$
Since we  are on $[0,1]$ we can choose infimum of all the $\epsilon_n$.

can we use Arzelà-Ascoli theorem now.

I haven't thought about these things in a long while but can you get inspiration from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3086427/show-that-this-operator-is-not-compact-using-arzela-ascoli?rq=1 ?

Let $[m,M]=g([0,1]).$ By assumption $m<M.$ Consider $$f_n(t)=\min \left (1,\left ({|t-m|\over M-m}\right )^n\right )$$ Then $\|f_n\|_\infty \le 1.$ The sequence   $$(Tf_{n})(x)=\left ({g(x)-m\over M-m}\right )^n$$ tends to $1$ when $g(x)=M$ and to $0$ when $ m\le g(x)<M.$ As the extreme values $m$ and $M$ are attained by $g(x)$ the pointwise limit of $Tf_n$ is not continuous. Hence $Tf_n$ does not contain a uniformly convergent subsequence.

thats nice construction i also had a thought of something raised to power but coudnt make it as you did

Suppose $g$ is not constant. Then there must exist points $x^*\in[0,1]$ so that for any $\epsilon>0$ you have an $x_\epsilon\in [x^*-\epsilon,x^*+\epsilon]$ so that $g(x_\epsilon)\neq g(x^*)$. (Else $g$ would be locally constant, and then constant since $[0,1]$ is connected.)
Let $x^*$ be such a point and for $\epsilon>0$ let $x_\epsilon\in B_\epsilon(x) $ be so that $g(x_\epsilon)\neq g(x)$. Define
$$f_\epsilon:[0,1]\to\Bbb R, \qquad x\mapsto\max\left(1-\frac{|x-g(x^*)|}{|g(x_\epsilon) -g(x^*)|},0\right)$$
Then $\|f_\epsilon\|=1$ and so if $T$ is compact it must follow that $\{T(f_\epsilon)\mid \epsilon >0 \}$ is equicontinuous.
But $T(f_\epsilon)(x_\epsilon)=1$, $T(f_\epsilon)(x)=0$. Since $x_\epsilon\to x$ as $\epsilon\to0$ you cannot have that $T(f_\epsilon)$ is equicontinuous, contradicting the assumption that $T$ is compact.
